# vb.net Picture box with a .png with a transparent background loaded in it?

Tags: vb.net, image, transparent

Ive got a .png file called donkey1.png - it has a transparent background and I have loaded it into a picturebox called pcbDonkey1 - I have changed the properties of the picturebox to have the backcolor transparent - This does not work as it still crosses over another image and has a white background.

I've heard about using GDI to draw this image so it will have a transparent image and be able to cross the over image without the white background.

How would you do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you need the PixtureBox control for something more than displaying an image, you can draw the image directly to the form in the Paint event:

Example (you will need to calculate aspect ratio etc., but in principle):

```
Sub Form_Paint(s as Object, e as PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.OnPaint

    Dim r As New Rectangle(myX, myY, myWidth, myHeight)
    e.graphics.DrawImage(myImage, r)

End Sub
```

Comment: @Andy To calc ratio you mean? To paint you can use the example, just replace variable names with what you have

Answer (score 6):

Just set the background picture to be the parent of the foreground picturebox and the transparancy will work without need for any additional coding

```
     With PictureBox1

        .Image = My.Resources._00_lichaam
        .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
    End With
    With PictureBox2
        .Parent = PictureBox1
        .Image = My.Resources._01_Hoofd
        .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
        .BackColor = Color.Transparent
    End With
```

That should work

Comment: Just used this with already drawn two picture box and done..! 
PictureBox2.Parent = PictureBox1